# Coplanarity of a polygonal chain

Tags: euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

If a closed polygonal chain of length 4 forms only right angles, is it necessary that the 4 points are coplanar and hence that the chain forms a rectangle? Is it still the case if it is only known for 3 of the angles?

A counterexample could be a tetrahedron with faces being right-triangles with the right angle at a different vertex each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ABC$ be a right triangle with hypothenuse $AC$, suppose that $\angle BCD$, $\angle CDA$, $\angle DAB$ are right. Let $D'$ be the projection of $D$ onto the plane of $ABC$, so that $ABCD'$ is a rectangle. By repeated use of Pythagoras,
$$(CD'^2+DD'^2)+(D'A^2+DD'^2)=CD^2+DA^2=AC^2=AB^2+BC^2.$$
Since $AB=CD'$ and $BC=D'A$, we can cancel them out to conclude $DD'=0$ and thus $D=D'$, meaning that $ABCD$ is a rectangle.

Comment: Why is $ABCD'$ a rectangle?

Comment: If $\angle BCD$ is right, so is $\angle BCD'$, likewise for $\angle D'AB$.